# How to use the lambda properly with pandas df?

Tags: python, pandas

I have few pandas df and those will need to be processed with few functions one after another. So, for a certain `df` after passing through the first function, the generated `df` will need to be processed with the sequential functions in the same way. The pseudo code might be as following,

```
df =  func_1(df)
df =  func_2(df)
df =  func_3(df)
```

and later be appended in a list, like `lis.append(df)`. With the loop, the code might like below,

```
storage = []
for df in dfs:
    for func in functions:
        df = func(df)
    storage.append(df)

 df = pd.concat(storage, ignore_index=True)
```

Eventually, I may use `concat` to produce the final df. The above code is what it suppose to be and my code is below. While the code runs perfectly, its not the same way the I intend.

```
storage = [map(lambda df: f(df) , dfs) for f in functions][-1]
df = pd.concat(storage, ignore_index=True)
```

For the storage, the right hand side produces an list with elements number equal to the dfs and the last element `(-1)` happens to be the `List Of 1 Element` process with the dfs with all the functions and conjuncted together. Here is the distinction, the previous `storage` list produce with all the dfs proceeded with the functions and the element number will be the same as the dfs.

My question: how can I use `lambda` function to get the storage list as I get before ? The list should contain the same number of elements equal to the number of the `dfs` and should be processed with all the functions.

I will try to explain it better if you have questions, but, please, consult before downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's break your task into pieces.

At first, you want to apply a list of functions to a same object. I'll stick with the simple example, but idea is the same. First, let's define a helper function, which accepts a list of functions and applies them to each other:

```
 apply_rec = lambda f, d: f[0](d) if len(f) == 1 else apply_rec (f[1:], f[0](d))
```

It accepts a list of functions and initial data. If the list contains exactly one function, it applies it to the data and returns the result; otherwise, it 'cuts' away first function from the list, apples it to data and calls itself with these inputs.

Let's try it:

```
 data = 10
 fs = [lambda x = x+1, lambda x = x * 2, lambda x = x ** 2]
 >>> apply_rec (fs, data)
484
```

Now you can do the following:

```
storage = [apply_rec (functions, df) for df in dfs]
```

I hope that understood your problem correctly.

Comment: You answer the question correctly and indeed, this is a great answer. Thanks a lot CAPTAIN.